# RJDBC dates all get returned as NA (Informix)

Tags: r, jdbc, informix, rjdbc

I'm using a RJDBC connection and can get most data fine. However, if I run a simple query like:
`SELECT * FROM dimDates`,
all column that are of type Date are full of NAs, even though they have concrete values in the database. The R code would be like this: `dbGetQuery(db_object, "SELECT * FROM dimDates")`
The database itself is Informix.

Is there a way to get correct dates into R from the database? I've tried including DBDATE=DMY4 in the connection string, but it doesn't seem to change anything.